# Import csv containing empty element into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, null, mysqlimport

I have a csv that looks like this:

```
20050104,000020.SZ,11432.90832
20050104,000013.SZ,
20050104,000008.SZ,
20050104,000014.SZ,1817.418592
20050104,000015.SZ,
20050104,000016.SZ,-544.482028
```

`   20050104,000017.SZ,10034.32188

I've read [theload-data documents of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) and right now I'm tring to load this file into MySQL using following codes:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.csv' INTO TABLE test1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

but It gives me the error:

```
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'value' at row 2
```

I tried to modified my code by changing \n into \r\n, that is:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'(date, code,value);
```

but it still gives me the same error.

I knew it was because of the empty fields that gives me an error, but I don't know how to avoid that. Can you help out?

Comment: No one can answer?

Comment: @Schwern Can you help me? The problem is that I don't want to change the row from 20050104,000013.SZ, to 20050104,000013.SZ